# How to include generic template in portlet's custom template

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I have Asset Publisher portlet and I want to create custom display template (ADT), where I want to use one of the generic templates (e.g. table, full-content). How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

while it might be possible to call out to the original templates, I don't expect them to be meant to be extended. And they're simple anyway. I'd just copy them and adapt to whatever you need.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Original templates are written in .jsp files. Can I just copy the code to the custom template form (.ftl or .vm)?

Comment: Oops, i didn't check that. No, these are different markups and you need to adapt jsp to FTL. However, my best guess for them is that they're quite trivial, so it shouldn't be a lot of wirk